# No response from Scala gRPC server only on GKE container

Tags: scala, google-kubernetes-engine, grpc, grpcurl

When the gRPC server is hosted on GKE container, and the service is called by grpcurl after port-forwarding to the target POD, onComplete is not processed and Timeout occurs.
And this server, strangely enough, works on the Docker process and on localhost

```
## Run from sbt console
> sbt server/run

## or Run from Docker image
> sbt clean docker:stage
> docker build -t test-server:latest ./server/target/docker/stage/
> docker run -d -p 8080:8080 test-server:latest

## Successfully requests.
> grpcurl -plaintext -vv -d '{"organizationId": "f"}' 0.0.0.0:8080 com.test.Server/CreateAccount

Resolved method descriptor:
rpc CreateAccount ( .com.test.Request ) returns ( .com.test.Request );

Request metadata to send:
(empty)

Response headers received:
content-type: application/grpc
grpc-accept-encoding: gzip

Estimated response size: 3 bytes

Response contents:
{
  "organizationId": "f"
}

Response trailers received:
(empty)
Sent 1 request and received 1 response
```

And this is the configuration of the app container.
The envoy is sidecarred, but it won't affect the app container since the only problem is port-forwarding to it.

```yaml
- containers
   - env:
    - name: JAVA_OPTS
      value: -Xms1500m -Xmx1500m
    - name: TZ
      value: Asia/Tokyo
    image: asia.gcr.io/my-project/test-server:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: admin
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      name: http
      protocol: TCP
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "1"
        memory: 2000Mi
      requests:
        cpu: "1"
        memory: 2000Mi
    securityContext: {}
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-bjhmx
      readOnly: true
```

As a result, there appears to be no header response from the server.
However, this could be a possible problem with grpcurl.

```
> kobectl port-forward server-xxxx-xxxx 8080:8080
> grpcurl -plaintext -vv -d '{"organizationId": "f"}' 0.0.0.0:8080 com.test.Server/CreateAccount

Resolved method descriptor:
rpc CreateAccount ( .com.test.Request ) returns ( .com.test.Request );

Request metadata to send:
(empty)

<-- waiting...
```

```scala
  // service implementation
  override def CreateAccount(request:Request): Future[Request] = {
    println("Received request.")
    Future(request)
  }

==================

object GrpcInterceptor extends ServerInterceptor with Injector {

  override def interceptCall[ReqT, RespT](
      serverCall: ServerCall[ReqT, RespT],
      headers: Metadata,
      next: ServerCallHandler[ReqT, RespT]
  ): ServerCall.Listener[ReqT] = {

    val listener = next.startCall(serverCall, headers)
    new ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener[ReqT](listener) {
      override def onHalfClose(): Unit = {
        println("On half close")
        super.onHalfClose()
      }
      override def onComplete(): Unit = {
        println("On complete")
        super.onComplete()
      }
      override def onMessage(message: ReqT) {
        println("On message")
        val value = message.asInstanceOf[GeneratedMessage]

        try {
          super.onMessage(message)
        } catch {
          case e: Throwable =>
            closeWithException(e, headers)
        }
      }

      private def closeWithException(t: Throwable, requestHeader: Metadata) = {
        println("Reciever intercept failed.", t)
        throw new StatusRuntimeException(Status.Code.INTERNAL.toStatus.withDescription(t.getMessage).withCause(t))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This implementation still does not output the "On complete" log on the GKE container.

```
On message
On half close
Received request.
```

However, only the GrpcReflectionApi seems to respond normally.

```
## On GKE port-forwarding
> grpcurl -plaintext 0.0.0.0:8080 list
com.test.TestServer
grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection
```

I can confirm that it works with the same Docker image, so the only thing I can think of is that it's either a GKE issue or there's some gRPC-specific processing that needs to be done. What other problems can you isolate?

Comment: I changed from ScalaPB GRPC to Akka-grpc and it worked.

Comment: If you solved your issue yourself @giiita then please add your fix as an answer to this question